# Php returning array from json, but I need the data as a string

Tags: php, arrays, rpc

So I'm setting up a little page for myself to see my online transactions in dogecoin.

I have the RPC server/client connection established and working correctly. 
The listtransactions method provides me with the transaction history as an array, which breaks down into its elements. I embed these in a table.

That all works correctly. what I WANT is to take the transaction ID and make it linkable to the dogecoin blockchain record.

Here is the code, and then I will note which lines have the issue:

```
    for($i=count($json)-1; $i>=0; $i--){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$json[$i]['address'].'</td>'."\n";
    //echo '<td>'.$json[$i]['category'].'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'.$json[$i]['amount'].'</td>'."\n";
    //echo '<td>'.$json[$i]['confirmations'].'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'."<a href='https://dogechain.info/tx/$json[$i]['txid']'>".$json[$i]
['txid'].'</a>        </td>'."\n";
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table></center>';
    ?>
```

The line containing the hyperlink is where it screws up. You can see how it is displaying at http://www.suchco.in/

an example link it gives me is: https://dogechain.info/tx/Array%5B
what it should be is: https://dogechain.info/tx/    fab3b949cb3a71e79fa6b631d5d16aa7268b77dc3626e2fb2e711f1b43adc08d

how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `{ }` around your array variables in a string.

Try:
`{$json[$i]['txid']}`

Instead of:
`$json[$i]['txid']`

OR

Do string concatenation

`echo '<td>'."<a href='https://dogechain.info/tx/".$json[$i]['txid']."'>"`